# Run brunch build and tests after to push into a git repo

Tags: git, brunch

Anybody knows a way to do the following: (Using brunch)

- push my app to one git repo
- execute the optimise, tests, jshint
- finally deploys the app

Is a plugin the only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a:

- update hook for JSHint (as in "[JSHint on Git Push (Update Hook)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10923103/6309)")
- post-update hook for deploying the app (as in "[using git to deploy my node.js app to my production server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12722130/using-git-to-deploy-my-node-js-app-to-my-production-server)")

A nice trick, on the repo representing your deployed app, is to add an attribute which will minify all css files.
See "[Compress JS/CSS files on deploy using Git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13706628/6309)"

---

My point is: if you need to trigger anything, even with grunt, you need to do so from a git commit.

[Paul Miller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1232668/paul-miller) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18522220/run-brunch-build-and-tests-after-to-push-into-a-git-repo/18525925?noredirect=1#comment27254408_18525925):

> You don't have to code anything.
>   **`brunch build`** will do the linting and stuff. Just put it as git hook.

That would be in a post-update hook then, with a cd to a non-bare repo in which you would:

```
unset GIT_DIR
git pull
brunch build
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include in the question that I'd like to use brunch for doing that (o trying at least)

Comment: @Lt. you can, but my point is: whatever process you will launch, they have to be launched from a git hook (update hook for JSHint, post-update for deployment).

Comment: @Lt. yes. Simply you might have to develop several plugin (if you want each step to be done by grunt), considering you have at least two git hook involved.

Comment: You don't have to code anything. `brunch build` will do the linting and stuff. Just put it as git hook.

Comment: @Lt. Paul Miller just added a comment for you. I have edited my answer to reflect his comment.